# Query on Pivot relation

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to query pivot model relation using Eloquent.

I've my User model :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function preferences(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Preference::class, 'user_preference')
                    ->using(UserNotificationPreference::class) //Custom Pivot model
                    ->withPivot([enabled, channel_id]);
    }
}
```

Here is the custom pivot model :

```
class UserNotificationPreference extends Pivot
{

    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'enabled' => 'boolean'
    ];

    /**
     * Channel relation.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function channel(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Channel::class);
    }
}
```

And the preference model :

```
class Preference extends Model
{
    //  protected $connection = "apodis";

    /**
     * The users that belong to the preference.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function users(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Preference::class, 'user_channel_notification_preference')
            ->using(UserNotificationPreference::class) //custom pivot
            ->withPivot(['preference_id', 'user_id', 'enabled', 'channel_id']);
    }
}
```

From a User model, i would like to retrieve Preferences after querying custom pivot table relationship (Channel::class) ,
something like :

```
$user->preferences()
     ->wherePivot('enabled', true)
     ->whereHasPivot('channel', function(Builder $query) {
        //doesn't exists
    })->get()
```

There is a way to achieve this ?

Comment: One option would be to set up a `hasMany` relationship with the pivot model itself.

Answer (score 0):

(Products Model Laravel) public function products() {
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
} (Shop Model Laravel)public function shops(){ return $this->belongsToMany('App\Shop');}  you can specify the actual field names of that pivot table   public function products(){  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','products_shops',  'shops_id', 'products_id');}possibility to get those values in our loops foreach ($shop-products as $product){echo $product->pivot->price;}